# jquery plugin Isotope not seeming to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to use the Isotope plugin for jquery
So, I have a website i am developing with jquery 1.9.1, jqueryui 1.10.1 and bootstrap 2.3.1.

I am trying to sort or even add items to the container and nothing seems to work. The events fire, the Isotope code gets called, yet nothing sorts and no items are added....

Here is a jsfiddle with jquery 1.9.1 and jquery 1.9.2, and no bootstrap... same result. What am I doing wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/w57zY/

Code in a nutshell:

HTML:

```
<div class="isoContainer" style="background-color: transparent">
  <div class="isoItem" data-collectiontag="Cool stuff">
    <more stuff>
  </div>
  <div class="isoItem" data-collectiontag="Zippy Stuff">
    <more stuff>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {

  var $container = $('#isoContainer');

  $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.isoItem',
      animationEngine: 'best-available',
      getSortData: {
          Catname: function ($elem) {
              return $elem.attr('data-collectionTag');
          }
      }


  });

  $('#randomBtn').click(function () {
      $('#isoContainer').isotope({
          sortBy: 'random'
      });
  });

  $('#descBtn').click(function () {
      $('#isoContainer').isotope({
          sortBy: 'Catname',
          sortAscending: false
      });
  });

  $('#AddBtn').click(function () {
      var $newItems = $('<div class="isoItem"  data-collectionTag="aaa"><span        style="text-align:center">aaa</span></div> </div><div class="isoItem"  data-collectionTag="zzz"><span style="text-align:center">zzz</span></div> </div>');
      $('#isoContainer').isotope( 'insert', $newItems );


  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var $container = $('#isoContainer');
```

Should be

```
var $container = $('.isoContainer');
```

As your html has a **class** isoContainer

```
<div class="isoContainer" style="background-color: transparent">
```

Alternatively, you can change your html from class="isoContainer" to id="isoContainer". I think this action would be best on your case.